# Connecting to FreeBSD Running on Virtual Machine Using WinSCP

Tags: ftp, freebsd, winscp

I'm a newbie in working with remote servers and in working with FreeBSD. I want to connect to the FreeBSD running on a virtual machine on my Windows 7 in order to be able to see the files with an explorer interface and be able to copy/paste files to and from it.
I have done this before a while ago using WinSCP but that time it took me 3 days to figure out the configurations I need to make the connection and unfortunately I can't remember them now and do not have another 3 days to waste!!

In my active networks I see to VMware Network adaptors (VMware is the virtual machine I am using) which have the IPv4s: 192.168.134.1 and 192.168.80.1 and when I run "ifconfig" on my virtual FreeBSD there is no IP address (except inet 127.0.0.1). The hostname of FreeBSD is "FreeBSD1" .

WinSCP requires me to fill in a file protocol which I think should be FTP **(correct me if I'm wrong; the other options are SFTP and SCP), a port number (which it sets to 21 by default for FTP) a hostname which I have tried "FreeBSD1", "192.168.134.1" and "192.168.80.1" with my username(root) and password.

When I use the hostname "FreeBSD1" I get the error:

> "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
>   Connection failed."

and for the other two I get:

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>   Connection failed."

The only thing is, as far as I remember, last time I tried (and succeeded after 3 days) "ifconfig" would show an IP which I think I used as hostname.

** For FTP it also requires an encryption which I set to no encryption. The other options are "SSL/TLS Implicit", "SSL Explicit" and "TLS Explicit".

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows machine does not recognize the FreeBSD1 hostname (*"The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"* error). So there's no point trying that further.

But it seems that the IPs work, just the FTP port 21 is not open (*"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"* error).

I would actually not expect that FreeBSD has unencrypted FTP port opened by default. I guess you will have more luck with SFTP (SSH).

Comment: You where right about the SFTP connection! But there was also another issue. Because of my system having slowed down I had disabled some of the services regarding VMware connections (NAT and DHCP) and I think that was why I didn't have any IP assigned to my FreeBSD. I enabled them and then FreeBSD had an IP which I used as my hostname and connected with SFTP via port 22.